# Loop fusion of Stream in Java-8 (how it works internally)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm reading the book 'Java in Action'.

And I saw an example code of Stream in the book.

```
List<String> names = menu.stream()
                         .filter(d -> {
                                       System.out.println("filtering" + d.getName());
                                       return d.getCalories() > 300;
                                      })
                         .map(d -> {
                                    System.out.println("mapping" + d.getName());
                                    return d.getName();
                                    })
                         .limit(3)
                         .collect(toList());
```

When the code is executed, the result is as follows.

```
filtering __1__.
mapping __1__.
filtering __2__.
mapping __2__.
filtering __3__.
mapping __3__.
```

That is, because of `limit(3)`, the log message is printed only 3 times!
In this book, this is called in "loop fusion."
But, I don't understand this.
Because, if you know whether an object is filtered, you have to calculate the filtering function. Then, "filtering ..." message is should be printed, I think.

Please, Explain me about how the loop fusion works internally.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

“Because, if you [want to] know whether an object is filtered, you have to calculate the filtering function”, is right, but perhaps your sample data wasn’t sufficient to illustrate the point. If you try

```
List<String> result = Stream.of("java", "streams", "are", "great", "stuff")
    .filter(s -> {
                  System.out.println("filtering " + s);
                  return s.length()>=4;
                 })
    .map(s -> {
               System.out.println("mapping " + s);
               return s.toUpperCase();
              })
    .limit(3)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("Result:");
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

it will print

```
filtering java
mapping java
filtering streams
mapping streams
filtering are
filtering great
mapping great
Result:
JAVA
STREAMS
GREAT
```

Showing that

- In order to find three elements matching the filter, you *might* have to evaluate more than three elements, here, four element are evaluated, but you don’t need to evaluate subsequent elements once you have three matches
- The subsequent mapping function only need to be applied to *matching* elements. This allows to conclude that it is irrelevant whether `.map(…).limit(…)`or `.limit(…).map(…)` was specified.
  This differs from the relative position of `.filter` and `.limit` which is relevant.

The term “loop fusion” implies that there is not a filtering loop, followed by a mapping loop, followed by a limit operation, but only one loop (conceptionally), performing the entire work, equivalent to the following single loop:

```
String[] source = { "java", "streams", "are", "great", "stuff"};
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
int limit = 3;
for(String s: source) {
    System.out.println("filtering " + s);
    if(s.length()>=4) {
        System.out.println("mapping " + s);
        String t = s.toUpperCase();
        if(limit-->0) {
            result.add(t);
        }
        else break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you got it wrong. `limit` is actually called `short-circuiting` (because it is executed only 3 times).

While `loop fusion` is `filter` and `map` executed at a single pass. These two operations where merged into a single one that is executed at each element.

You **do not see** output like this:

```
 filtering
 filtering
 filtering


 mapping
 mapping
 mapping
```

Instead you see `filter` followed immediately by a `map`; so these two operations were *merged* into  a single one.

Generally you should not care how that is done internally (it build a pipeline of these operations), because this might change and it is implementation specific.